# TypeError: _chart.registerables is not iterable (cannot read property undefined)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, chart.js

I'm trying to test my react aplication, but when the test starts with the **'npm test'** the first message I got is.

**TypeError: _chart.registerables is not iterable (cannot read property undefined)**.

I don't know how to fix this, because I'm using a external library called ChartJs.

I started my test as usual:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import App from './App';

  // testing login screen
describe('Testando a tela de Login', () => {

  afterEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());

  // I will try to verify the login screen elements.
  it('Verificando se os elementos estão contidos na tela.', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    localStorage.clear()

    render(
      <Router history={ history }>
        <App />
      </Router>
    );

  });
});
```

Then I try to run the test... You can see I didn't implemented any verification, just runned the test script

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _chart.registerables is not iterable (cannot read property undefined)

      4 | import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
      5 |
    > 6 | ChartJS.register(...registerables);
        |         ^
      7 |
      8 | function PieChart({ chartData }) {
      9 |   return (

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/PieChart.jsx:6:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/MainUserScreen.jsx:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.jsx:5:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:4:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
```

I looked into others similar errors here on the stackoverflow and the library from jest and ChartJS, but I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your chart.js version to 4.1.1

It looks like it's not supported in your version of charts.js, in 4.1.1 it will be fine (in my case it was)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it